# Polymer 1.0 hidden$ attribute negate operator

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Just trying to apply negate operator, it seems not working, any input on this appreciated.

it is definitely not a blocker, i can write a compute method to handle it, but negate operator makes more sense to me at-least.

Below snippet not working, if i remove the negate operator it works in opposite way of what i expect.

```html
<div hidden$="{{!productDetails}}">
  My Hidden Content
</div>
```

Documentation (not a comprehensive one)

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html

Comment: In a [data binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html) section of polymer documentation: <div hidden="{{!enabled}}"></div> ie. there is no '$'.

Comment: Are you sure that your `productDetails` has `type: Boolean`? If not, that could be your issue.

Comment: Below answer looked bit more cleaner way to handle this specific case, thank you for the input guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [DOM if](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-if)

```
<dom-module id="user-page">

  <template>

    All users will see this:
    <div>{{user.name}}</div>

    <template is="dom-if" if="{{user.isAdmin}}">
      Only admins will see this.
      <div>{{user.secretAdminStuff}}</div>
    </template>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'user-page',
      properties: {
        user: Object
      }
    });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1):

The hidden attribute is complicated with regard to undefined values. Consider the following in your polymer template:

```
<div hidden="{{ prop1}}">this is hidden on prop1     </div>
<div hidden="{{!prop1}}">this is hidden on not prop1 </div>
```

If prop1 is undefined, both divs are visible. In other words:

(when prop1 is undefined)
prop1  = false 
!prop1 = false

When prop1 is assigned a value, one of the elements will disappear.

(when prop1 is 5)
prop1  = true
!prop1 = false